# How to promote more answers?

Tags: discussion

Here is a problem I'm having. Tylershads gave a great answer to my [last question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/how-many-tarantino-films-are-set-in-the-same-universe). I would say it's pretty much the definitive answer, however one of the problems I know this site is having in becoming a regular site instead of Beta is that a lot of questions get one response. I've started making a habit of waiting longer to award an answer to help encourage more answers but it doesn't always help. I feel this question even though it has a great answer could have more answers given, not necessarily different with the main information but with more angles or perspectives thrown in. There seems to be more in the [comments inside of this Reddit link](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ubaqq/what_fan_theories_have_blown_your_mind_with_their/c4tzvnn) that Tylershads links to in the comments on this answer. Now this doesn't really have to do with this specific question it's just the example that I'm using to ask how can we encourage more answers to one question? These are movies and tv shows there should be lots of opinions out there.

Comment: Very good question.  Unfortunately I don't have a good answer.

Comment: @iandotkelly Well here's to hoping that this question at least gets more than one answer.

Comment: Irony would be with you.

Comment: Plot-explanation questions are the maximum which can fairly be answered in a single answer.Analytical questions are lesser in number.

Answer (score 9):

I think part of the problem is that a decent amount of our questions are easily answered in one to two answers.  The questions that tend to get the most answers are, of course, identification questions.

The analytical questions on movies that are deeper tend to get a wider range of answers, but those movies aren't as popular.   I think it's something that we can't easily fix.

Comment: In a way, it stems back to finding a way to encourage more analysis and examination of pieces, and maintaining a balance between that and simple plot-related questions.

Comment: Plot related questions are pretty high than that of other analysis questions. I thank those questioners also who ask good questions eg. Shane Finerman who ask a lot of good analytical questions.

Comment: *"but those movies aren't as popular"* - It's not a question of movies but a question of, well, questions. You don't need some French drama from the 60s (stereotypes intended!) to ask a good analysis question (yet, I might agree that it's slightly harder for, say, *Transformers*, even if not impossible). So it's not that the necessary movies are less popular, but the respective good questions on popular movies. Trivia and plot-holes just drag far more attention, but you don't need a "dumb" movie for those.